# Hibernate transaction rollback with spring is not working right

Tags: hibernate, spring

Spring 3.0.0
Hibernate 3
MySQL 5
JBoss 5

I have an app using Spring's hibernate transactions. I have an update that affects two tables, and if there is an exception on the second update, the first update does not get rolled back.

Interestingly, I created a small test  java app that does not use Spring, but uses explicit Hibernate transaction management, and uses the exact same Hibernate configuration and the same JBoss data source configuration, and things work fine. Hibernate is clearly setting auto-commit to false, and then setting it back to true after the transaction is done. Rollback correctly rolls back the first update.

**Here is my Spring configuration:**

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:TappDataMySqlDS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        singleton="true">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
                        <list>
                                <value>A.hbm.xml</value>
                                <value>B.hbm.xml</value>
                         </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionAttributeSource"
class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource" />

    <bean id="com.tapp.tss.core.dao.SyncDAO" class="com.tapp.tss.core.dao.SyncDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao.proxy.SyncDAO"
class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="target" ref="com.tapp.tss.core.dao.SyncDAO" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**The Dao code:**

```
public void save() {
Session session = org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession();

try {
A a = new A();
B b = new B();

a.setPropName("abc");
a.setPropValue("xyz");

b.setFieldName("abc");
b.setFieldValue("xyz");

a.getASet().add(b);

session.save(a);
session.flush();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    if (autoConnRelease) {
        releaseSession(session);                
    }
}
```

Yes, I googled a lot this problem but didn't really find a solution. I have no idea what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using innodb tables in mysql? Try using the `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect` dialect, rather than the generic one you're using... Also, I can't see in your code/configuration where you configure the transaction management for the method `save`.